# Fetching from localhost server in Create React App during development vs fetching from deployment during production

Tags: reactjs, express, fetch, create-react-app, nodemailer

This is a personal portfolio page that I'm implementing a contact form within, using nodemailer.

The nodemailer thing is all set from server side. I just need some advice on pointing the client post request to the right place in regards to development and deployment.

I figured as much for setting an environment variable for production vs development and hitting the fetch based upon that.  Now I'm just wondering how to go about finding whatever I would put in the fetch for production.

would it be just pointing back into my own app:
 `fetch(www.mydomain.com/send-email, data) ...`

I'm in the Heroku docs trying to figure this out.

Basically, I have a huge blind spot which is hitting a server API from Create React App that isn't launched independently on localhost:3000. I have yet to hit a server route from my client that wasn't served locally on localhost.  When I push this to Heroku, I need to have the right route or config, what I need is some advice on how to do this.

I understand proxying somewhat.  Just wondering what the steps are to properly hit my server route from an client/server deployed on Heroku as opposed to localhost:3000 during deployment.

When I'm in development I pretty much always axios.post a server that I've spun up on localhost:3000,
which I then hit with something like this coming from my client..

```
axios.post('localhost:3000/send-email', data)
      .then( () => {
        setSent(true) 
      })
      .then(() => {
        resetForm()
      })
      .catch((err)=> {
        console.log('Message not sent', err)
      })
  }
```

...which is then handled by an endpoint on the express server listening on localhost:3000, that looks somewhat like what I've pasted below.

```
const express = 
  require('express'), 
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'), 
  nodemailer = require('nodemailer'), 
  cors = require('cors'), path = require('path'), 
  port = process.env.PORT || 3000, publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build');
require('dotenv').config();
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'));
});

app.post('/send-email', (req, res) => {
  console.log('request: ', req.body)
  let data = req.body;
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    port: 465,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL,
      pass: process.env.PASSWORD
    }
  });

  let mailOptions = {
    from: data.email,
    to: process.env.EMAIL,
    subject: `${data.subject}`,
    html: `<p>${data.name}</p>
            <p>${data.email}</p> 
            <p>${data.message}</p>`
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,
  (err, res) => {
    if(err) {
      res.send(err)
    } else {
      res.send('Success')
    }
    transporter.close();
  });
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}!`);
});
```

folder structure is like this:

```
main
 |-server
  |-server.js
 |-src
  |-components
    |-Contact.js
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable to differ the environments.

> When you run `npm start`, it is always equal to `'development'`, when you run `npm test` it is always equal to `'test'`, and when you run `npm run build` to make a production bundle, it is always equal to `'production'`. **You cannot override `NODE_ENV` manually**.

Therefore, you can create and export a function like

```
export function apiDomain() {
    const production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    return production ? 'anotherDoman' : 'localhost:3000'
}
```

or maybe, depending on your requirements

```
export function apiDomain() {
    const { protocol, hostname, origin } = window.location
    return hostname === 'localhost' ? `${protocol}//${hostname}` : origin
}
```

For more details, take a look at https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: thank you I figured as much for setting it based upon environment variable.  see edits....."would it be just pointing back into my own app:  fetch(www.mydomain.com/send-email, data) ..."